# The cart, checkout, and shop links not getting removed

Tags: menus, woocommerce-offtopic, navigation, links

I uninstalled woocommerce plugin but yet the shop, checkout and cart links in navigation bar is persistent. The theme I'm using is Compass. But whatever theme I choose those three links do not vanish. I want to create a simple blogging website for myself. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, my bad. I'm new to wordpress so I did not know that the pages created my plugins persists even when they are uninstalled. I had to delete cart, shop, and checkout from pages.